# Java, Checking to see if two char arrays are equal

Tags: java

I have two character arrays in Java:

`orig_array` and `mix_array`. I need to check if they are not equal.

Here is what I have so far:

```
sample data
orig_team=one
mix_team=neo

while(!Arrays.equals(mix_team, orig_team))
{

    if (Arrays.equals(mix_team, orig_team))
    {

        System.out.println("congradulations! you did it");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    else {

        System.out.println("enter the index");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scn.nextInt();
        int y = scn.nextInt();
        char first=mix_team[x];
        char second=mix_team[y];
        mix_team[x]=second;
        mix_team[y]=first;
        for (int i = 0; i < mix_team.length; i = i + 1) 
        {
            System.out.print(i);  
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(mix_team);
    }
}
```

How can I determine if the two arrays are equal?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input for orig_team and mix_team?

Comment: @Jeremy, I have put the sample data. mix_team is basically shuffled version of orig_team.

Comment: Bah; no need for `else` if the `if` condition exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have the following loop:

```
while (something) {
    if (! something) {
        code();
    }
}
```

The code inside the `while` loop will only run if `something` evaluates to `true`. Thus, the value of `!something` will always be false, and the `if` statement's contents will not be run.

Instead, try:

```
while (!Arrays.equals (mix_team, orig_team)) {
    System.out.println("enter the index");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scn.nextInt();
    int y = scn.nextInt();
    char first=mix_team[x];
    char second=mix_team[y];
    mix_team[x]=second;
    mix_team[y]=first;
    for (int i = 0; i < mix_team.length; i = i + 1) 
    {
        System.out.print(i);  
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(mix_team);
}
System.out.println("congratulations! you did it");
System.exit(0);
```

---

By the way, you don't need to create a scanner each time. A better way to do it would be to declare the scanner before the `while` loop (basically move the initialization line up two lines).

Answer (score 3):

The `while` loop's block is only executed when the two arrays are *not* equal, so starting that block with the same equality check makes no sense. In other words, the line:

```
if (Arrays.equals(mix_team, orig_team))
```

...will always be `false`.